How to mock global variable, when the value is coming from a function python unittest
I have to mock the global variable in python, but the variable value is coming from the another function. When i am importing the file, this function is getting run but instead of this, I want the mock values there.
secrets.py
import traceback
import logging
import boto3
import os
import json


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

secret_name = os.environ['SECRETS_NAME']
region_name = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
config_secret = dict()

def init_config_secret():

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    try:

        config_secret_value = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)

        if 'SecretString' in config_secret_value:
            global config_secret
            config_secret = json.loads(config_secret_value['SecretString'])

        return config_secret
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Error while retrieving secrets')
        traceback.print_exc()


def get_config_secret():
    if not bool(config_secret):
        return init_config_secret()
    else:
        return config_secret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_config_secret()

request_auth.py
import requests
from secrets import get_config_secret
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

config = get_config_secret()

print(f'config: {config}')

token = None

def verifySSL() :
    return True


def get_api_root_url():
    return config["url"]


def build_request_header(access_token, content_type):

    return {
        "authorization" : access_token,
        "Content-Type" : content_type
    }


def get_access_token():
    global token
    if token is None:
        acquire_token()
    elif token["expiry"] < datetime.now():
        acquire_token()

    return token["authToken"]


def acquire_token():
    auth_payload = {
        "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
        "client_id" : config["id"]
    }
    response = requests.post(config["url"], data = auth_payload, verify = verifySSL())
    # print(response.json())

    global token
    token= dict()
    token["authToken"] = response.json()["access_token"]
    token["expiry"] = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes = 10)


test_request_auth.py
import json, sys
import unittest, os
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from unittest import mock


from request_auth import *  


class TestRequestAuth(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("request_auth.config", {"test": "test"})
    @patch("request_auth.get_config_secret")
    def test_get_api_root_url(self, mock_get_config_secret):
        mock_get_config_secret.return_value = {"url": "test"}
        self.assertEqual(get_api_root_url(), "https://test.test.com/")

I tried this way, but not working not sure what need to be done.
can anyone please help with it?

You are patching global variables after they have been already loaded into memory during import. After applying patches, you are supposed to reload the module using importlib.
import importlib
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from request_auth import *  


class TestRequestAuth(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("request_auth.get_config_secret")
    def test_get_api_root_url(self, mock_get_config_secret):
        mock_get_config_secret.return_value = {"url": "test"}

        importlib.reload(module=request_auth)

        self.assertEqual(get_api_root_url(), "https://test.test.com/")

